# Django - DeleteView with pk. No Posty matches the given query

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, primary-key, reverse

I have a problem with `get_success_url`.

Namely I would delete a comment from post and then should go back to the page with the post. On this moment have I "No Posty matches the given query." I dont have idea how i can resolve this. I know how to reverse on page with no pk ;(

Models

```
class Posty(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    sub_title = models.SlugField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(default="avatar.png",upload_to="images", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['png','jpg','jpeg'])])
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    T_or_F = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posty'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.sub_title:
            self.sub_title = slugify(self.title)
        super(Posty,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home:detail_post', kwargs={"id":self.id})
```

Views

```
class delete_post_comment(DeleteView):
    model = CommentModelForm()
    template_name = 'delete_comment_from_post.html'

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Posty,id=id_)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('home:detail_post')
```

Urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('forum/', create_post_and_comment, name='forum'),
    path('delete_post/<int:pk>/', delete_post_view.as_view(model=Posty), name='delete_post'),
    path('update_post/<int:pk>/', update_post_view.as_view(model=Posty), name='update_post'),
    path('delete_post_comment/<int:pk>/', delete_post_comment.as_view(model=CommentPost), name='delete_post_comment'),
    path('update_post_comment/<int:pk>/', update_post_comment.as_view(model=CommentPost), name='update_post_comment'),

    path('detail_post/<int:pk>/', contact, name='detail_post'),
    path('testuje/<int:pk>/', contact, name='test')
```

Forms

```
class CommentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={}))
    class Meta:
        model = CommentPost
        fields = ('content1',)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I can see a couple of issues here. First the `model` class attribute is actually a form, not a model. So you'll need to change that to `CommentPost` as I assume that's the model for comments and that's what you want to delete.

You've changed `get_object` to get a `Posty` object which will then delete it. If you then try to redirect back to the detail view of the `Posty` object that's been deleted you'd expect to get the error that you are seeing, because you just deleted the `Posty` object matching the query.

It looks like you'll need to pass the comment ID and the `Posty` ID into this view

Also you need to include the ID with your `reverse` because the URL requires an ID. So if the `id` in the GET params is the `Posty` ID then the following will work;

```
class delete_post_comment(DeleteView):
    model = CommentModelForm()
    template_name = 'delete_comment_from_post.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'home:detail_post'
            kwargs={'id': self.kwargs.get("id")}
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Views

```
class delete_post_comment(DeleteView):
    model = CommentPost
    template_name = 'delete_comment_from_post.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('home:detail_post', kwargs={'pk': self.object.post.pk})
```